# Method in Azure DevOps .NET SDK suddenly goes obsolete and stops working

Tags: c#, .net, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Currently working on a sort of test collection script for QA; its goal for now is to search the company Azure project for test cases that have majority N/A (not applicable) test results. Earlier today I was debugging a rewritten version that searches based on the id of a test plan as opposed to a WIQL query (another bag of worms foreshadowing the kind of library structuring Microsoft is making me deal with), and after finally getting it to work, I set about restructuring some things to make the script less clunky. That went out the window when suddenly, my script stops running at all, and my only clue as to why is an error Visual Studio throws at a line which never had problems before:

> CS0612    'TestCompatHttpClientBase.GetTestSuitesForPlanAsync(string, int, int?, int?, int?, bool?, object, CancellationToken)' is obsolete

Literally earlier today, this wasn't a problem. I've tried searching for non-deprecated/obsolete methods that match the desired return type, I've tried adding a parameter to trick VS into thinking I'm using a (hopefully non-obsolete) overload of the method, and I don't know what else to try because this is *literally my second month* as a totally-not-overqualified-intern-that's-basically-a-developer.

At this point my only theory is that some engineer over at Redmond, Washington pushed a change sometime today that broke my script. If so, you hear me, Microsoft?!

What else am I supposed to do.

IMPORTANT(?) EDIT: The Azure SDK docs show a slightly different GetTestSuitesForPlanAsync function that takes a `Nullable<SuiteExpand>` for the third parameter instead of a `Nullable<int>`. Trying to access this, both through a new `using` line or putting in a third parameter of the former aforementioned type, hasn't worked so far.

Code for context (edited for posterity):

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.WebApi;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi.Models;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

static internal async Task<List<TestCaseResult>> collectTestCaseResultsByPlan(TestManagementHttpClient client, WorkItem plan)
        {
            //for anyone unfamiliar, this is how azure tests are structured: plan > suite > case > results/runs
            List<TestCaseResult> results = new List<TestCaseResult>();
            string projectName = "[REDACTED]";
            try
            {
                //The bad apple that spoils the bunch. Now obsolete for whatever reason. Causes the program to terminate without even an exception.
                List<TestSuite> suites = await client.GetTestSuitesForPlanAsync(projectName, (int)plan.Id);
                foreach (var suite in suites)
                {
                    List<SuiteTestCase> cases = await client.GetTestCasesAsync(projectName, (int)plan.Id, suite.Id);
                    foreach (var testCase in cases)
                    {
                        var testQuery = new TestResultsQuery
                        {
                            ResultsFilter = new ResultsFilter
                            {
                                TestCaseId = Convert.ToInt32(testCase.Workitem.Id),
                                AutomatedTestName = "test" //don't ask
                            }
                        };
                        TestCaseResult caseQuery = client.GetTestResultsByQueryAsync(testQuery, projectName).Result;
                        results.AddRange(caseQuery.Results);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) //Has yet to catch anything.
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
            return results;
        }
```

Comment: Did you try to use `TestPlanHttpClient`, not `TestCompatHttpClient`?

Comment: @DanielMann not actually sure how to do that, `client` itself is of the `TestManagementHttpClient` class and I assume it's pulling from `TestCompatHttpClient`. Actually, I should make an edit in the post to clarify something I think could be important...

Comment: Update your question and include your `using` statements. Also share the specific NuGet packages you're installing (probably `PackageReference`s in your CSProj file)

Comment: NuGet Package is the latest version, 16.170.0. Both uninstalling and reinstalling in addition to installing the Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient haven't worked.

Comment: Based on the docs, you're using the wrong namespace. `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.TestManagement.TestPlanning.WebApi`. See the obsolete [TestCompat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.testmanagement.webapi.testcompathttpclientbase.gettestsuitesforplanasync?view=azure-devops-dotnet) vs [non-obsolete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.services.testmanagement.testplanning.webapi.testplanhttpclientbase.gettestsuitesforplanasync?view=azure-devops-dotnet-preview).

Comment: Tried putting that in the `using` section. VS said the namespace didn't exist.

Comment: Sidenote: I have low reputation so I can't use chat. I had the wrong prefixes when I tried to include TestPlanning earlier. Now that I have `using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.TestManagement.TestPlanning.WebApi;`, my next issue is figuring out how to get VS to use the non-deprecated version instead. I've already tried `using TestSuite = Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.TestManagement.TestPlanning.WebApi.TestSuite;`, and I can't do the same with `GetTestSuitesForPlanAsync` swapped in for `TestSuite`.

Comment: I also already tried putting in `SuiteExpand.Children` as a third parameter for the problem function. VS still wants to think of that third parameter as an `int` instead of a `SuiteExpand`.